# How to set the HTML video title that is shown in Chrome and Windows?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, html5-video, mediasession

How can I set the name (label) of HTML5 `<video>` element that browsers (like Chrome) and Windows OS display?

Like the title that Windows shows for this youtube video (when changing speaker volume):

[image]

Currently for me the page title is shown (the title set in page `head`).
I tried adding a `title="..."` attribute to the `video` element but it had no effect. Also didn't find a solution on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer stated, it can be done with JavaScript and [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API).
Check out [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Ft6diPReUAU).

```js
if ("mediaSession" in navigator) {
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: "Unforgettable",
    artist: "Nat King Cole",
    album: "The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)",
    artwork: [
      { src: "https://dummyimage.com/128x128", sizes: "128x128", type: "image/png" },
      { src: "https://dummyimage.com/512x512", sizes: "512x512", type: "image/png" }
    ]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for the video. But in some browsers, mediaSession worked for me. Javascript...

```
    if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
      navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
      title: 'name',
      artist: '',
      album: '',
      artwork: [{ src: '...' }]
      });
  }
```